# Having trouble unsetting $_SESSION variables on hosted server

Tags: php, session

So let me preface this by saying I'm not the most experienced php developer and don't have the most solid understanding of servers.. but I'm stumped and am unsure of what to use so I'm open to any suggestions.

So I'm making a website where you go through a series of pages and on each page a different `$_SESSION` variable is set, until finally all the `$_SESSION` variables are used to query the db. Also, when the user returns to the index page at any time, I need to unset all the `$_SESSION` variables so that the process isn't affected. Also, this process works perfectly on my localhost (i use wampserver) but I cannot seem to unset the variables on my hosted server for some reason.

On the index page I'm setting the `session_save_path()` and then found this process online to unset the session and delete it and then create a new one.

```
<?php
    ini_set('session.save_path', '/home3/www/public_html/test/session');
    session_name();
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_write_close();
    setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
    session_regenerate_id(true);
?>
```

The problem with this process is that none of my `$_SESSION` variables stay set past the next page and I don't understand why..

I've also tried this same process without the `setcookie()` and the `session_regenerate_id()`, which allows me to pass the `$_SESSION` variables between all the pages, but they no longer unset when I return to the index page..

I'm not the most experienced with this and I don't understand fully how `$_SESSION`'s work and I may have missed something fairly simple so any suggestions would be great! thanks

Comment: Do you call session_start() on every page? You don't seem to be doing that.

Comment: yes I have called session_start() at the beginning of every page

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. Not sure why this worked but here goes.

The code above was used at the very beginning of the index page, the idea being that any time the user hit the index page it would wipe the `$_SESSION`.

What fixed it was taking the process

```
<?php
   ini_set('session.save_path', '/home3/www/public_html/test/session');
   session_name();
   session_start();
   session_unset();
   session_destroy();
   session_write_close();
   setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
   session_regenerate_id(true);
?>
```

and putting it in its own script that would get called instead, before returning to the index page.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

Again, not sure how this fixed it, but still nice to have it working.